# Is there a way to launch an ironpython interactive window inside a windows forms app

Tags: c#, python, winforms, ironpython

I am looking to launch an ironpython interactive window when I run a python script from my windows forms application. I am looking to redirect the python IO to the interactive window. Therefore, the script can take user input while it is running.

I have created an application in windows forms (C#) which hosts ironpython 2.7.9. I made a simple GUI which allows me to select a python script with an OpenFileDialog() and run it using an engine. Up until now, my scripts did not require user input and were completely automated from start to finish. However, now I am looking to include manual steps within these scripts which require the user to enter 'y' or 'n' to continue or abort the script. With the winforms application printing all output to the console, I am unable to interact with the python script at run time. Ideally, I was looking to launch an ironpython interactive window when I run my script and be able to interact with the python script from there. From what I was able to gather online, it seems I would have to hard-code a path to the ipy.exe file in my computers Program Files and redirect python input/output somehow but this is not ideal. I figure there has to be an easier way to do this but cannot figure out how. Ultimately, I am just trying to give user input to a python script running in C#, so if there are any other methods that can satisfy this I would be receptive to those ideas. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, also let me know if there is more information I need to provide!

How I created my engine:

```
public ScriptExecutor()
        {
             InitializeComponent();
             myEngine = Python.CreateEngine();
        }

private Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine myEngine;
```

I run a script with the ExecuteFile function:

```
myEngine.ExecuteFile(@"path to file");
```

Expected result would be to launch a python interactive window when a "run script" button is clicked. The user can interact with the script from this interactive window (give input/see the output)

picture of GUI: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWtOr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

After alot of experimenting I found the answer to this question.

I realized that I should not use an engine for the functionality I was looking for. Instead creating a process is the best way to launch the ironPython window.
Every tutorial and question I saw was saying to redirect the output with ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true

However, if you want the ipy console to act as a stand alone process, we need to allow it to receive input and output, hence these values must remain false.
UseShellExecute and CreateNoWindow must also be set to false so that the operating system shell does not start the process and a new ipy interactive window is launched.

also, since ipy.exe is installed to the System32 folder I do not need to hard code the path, rather just use "ipy.exe"

To launch the python interactive window I started a process:

```
var script = @"C:\path\to\script.py";
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "ipy.exe",
    Arguments = $"\"{script}\"",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = false
};

Process python = new Process();
python.StartInfo = psi;
```